# Example of a ring with no minimal prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am a math student, in the course of abstract algebra we have shown that in a unitary commutative ring every ideal I possesses at least one minimal prime ideal. I am trying to find an example of ideal contents in a non-commutative (not unitary) ring that does not possess a minimal prime ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ does not have any prime ideals.

If you want an $R$ such that $R^2\neq 0$, then $2\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Hi, do you have an example of a ring that have some prime ideals but there is an ideal that is not contained in any of them?

Comment: Take $R$ to be one of the rings above, and use $R\times F_2$.  Its only prime is $R\times \{0\}$ but $\{0\}\times F$ is not contained in it.